# How to centre picture box

Tags: c#, .net, image, picturebox

I am trying to use [this plugin](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/15373/A-scrollable-zoomable-and-scalable-picture-box) for C#, which works great.  However I am having difficulty getting the image to center when zooming in.  By default, whenever zooming, the picture box focuses on the top left corner. I would like it to focus on the centre.

Any idea? I have searched far and wide and cannot find an example which does this within this plugin.

Comment: Are You using `WinForms` or `WPF`?

Comment: @Tatranskymedved Winforms

Comment: From the posted article, there are 2 options: You can either download the original source code and modify it, so You will center the picture Yourself. OR You can create wrapper for the functions zoom functions. Once the button will be pressed, You will call the zoom in, and then move the camer(picture) to the correct coordinations.

Comment: @Tatranskymedved - How can it be moved to the co ordinates?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7798999/7167572

Comment: @Tatranskymedved Does that work with the plugin or only a .NET picture box?

Comment: @Tatranskymedved Tried it but did not work

Comment: see my answer. I tried both implementation and both works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, this getting complicated so I will write complete answer:

The plugin is not open in the way You can hook on the zooming events. Actualy thing You can do (as You have open sources) is to "hack" inside - change the source code and adjust to Your needs.

Options:

**1. Change inner implementation:**

Get to file `ScalablePictureBoxImp.cs` , find method `ScalePictureBoxToFit()`, and add the codes after lines:

```
//some previous code
this.pictureBox.Left = left;
this.pictureBox.Top = top;
this.AutoScroll = true;

// add this line under:
this.AutoScrollPosition = new Point(this.Width / 2, this.Height / 2);
```

Now You can simply use the component as before, and it will do all the things just with resizing them on middle (it possibly need some more math to fit the screen properly).

**2. Change outer implementation:**

Author is ussing wrapper for the inner implementation, where he is hooking on the events and You are just using the wrapped object (it is like pressing the buttons on a mouse instead of connecting 1 wire with some other).

In file `ScalablePictureBox.cs` edit the Constructor and add following implementation:

```
public ScalablePictureBox()
{
    //some code ...


    this.pictureTracker.ScrollPictureEvent += new PictureTracker.ScrollPictureEventHandler(this.scalablePictureBoxImp.OnScrollPictureEvent);
    this.pictureTracker.PictureTrackerClosed += new PictureTracker.PictureTrackerClosedHandler(this.pictureTracker_PictureTrackerClosed);

    //Enter the line below to hook on event
     this.scalablePictureBoxImp.ZoomRateChangedEvent += ScalablePictureBoxImp_ZoomRateChangedEvent;
}
```

Now You have hooked on the event of zooming, and You just need to adjust the scrolling:

```
private void ScalablePictureBoxImp_ZoomRateChangedEvent(int zoomRate, bool isFullPictureShown)
{
    this.scalablePictureBoxImp.AutoScrollPosition = new Point(this.Width / 2, this.Height / 2);
}
```

Inner implementation of the ScalablePictureBox is invoking event `ZoomRateChangedEvent` -> Once this zoom change, You will get the size of a window and move the scroll buttons to the middle position. This can be adjusted in any way You requiring.

*I believe, originaly autor wanted to write `ScalablePictureBoxImp` only and the wrapper was added just for test/simply case purpose. It is completely up to You if You write it all Yourself or adjust -> Correct way should be using the outer implementation then.*

Comment: I just tried this and it seems to have moved the position of the side tracker, but not to the center. It is slightly under the top-left corner now

Comment: If it makes a difference, I am zooming in by 250% on button click in my application

Comment: Please use logical thinking and analysis, adjust the values You are requiring so they produce expected results.

Comment: I would have come up with the same reasoning as you - width / 2 and height / 2. Any idea why it is not working like that?

Comment: I'm sorry, but this question is too broad & I'm limited with time. You know how to change position now You just need to use some math to find where the point is & how it changes relative to Width/Height of window, width/heigh of the image or any other Property you can colerate to.

Comment: I would also like to point out that you are very kind for helping me when you didn't have to. Thank you very very much :)